# How does one get Drupal's current view/page identifier?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

What I am looking for is a page_id/view_id that I can use to identify and style specific pages. I would use the title or the url, but there is a chance that it could change if the a higher-up decides that the page should no longer be called Golf, but rather Tee-Time because he likes it better.

Presumably this identifier would not change if the current page were to be a paged view (page 1,2,3,4...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of solving this is the following. It's depending on the url, so if it changes, so does the class-name.

In my themes template.php I implemented hook_preprocess_page:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  $body_classes = array();
  $body_classes[] = 'page-' . _get_page_name($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  $vars['body_classes'] = implode(' ', $body_classes);
}

function _get_page_name($request_uri) {
  static $numeric_subsection = array(
    '/node/' => 'node',
  );

  $preAlias = $request_uri;
  $alias = substr(strrchr($preAlias, "/"), 1);
  if (strpos($alias, '?') > -1) {
    $alias = substr($alias, 0, strpos($alias, '?'));
  }

  $page_name = $alias;
  if (empty($alias)) {
    $page_name = 'start';
  }
  else if (is_numeric($alias)) {
    foreach ($numeric_subsection as $section => $pn) {
       if (strpos($preAlias, $section) > -1) {
         $page_name = $pn;
       }
    }
  }

  return $page_name;
}
```

Then in the main page-template:

```
<body class="<?php print $body_classes; ?>">
```

This isn't a generic solution. So you'll probably have to customize this for your specific needs. It will for example need som tweaking to play nicely with path auto.

Answer (score 1):

This depends a little on how your site is put together (panel pages, view pages, "normal" pages).  Essentially, you need to figure out what vars are in scope, and then determine which information in them can be used.  To determine what is in scope, you can use `print_r(array_keys(get_defined_vars()));` and then poke around in the individual vars.

An option is to do something in `theme_preprocess_page`.  One option is to get the page data via `page_manager_get_current_page()`, poke around in there, and then add body classes as needed.  Without knowing what you are doing, you essentially need to `print_r` the results somewhere, look at what you have, and go from there.